# Is it possible to create a policy that will conditionally expose an api management endpoint in azure even when a opim-subscription key is required?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

An example of what I am looking for is as follows but the allow-access element does not exist. What can I replace  with so that the subscription key is not checked. i.e. in this case it would allow all callers access to the controller as long as they are making GET requests.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(context.Request.Method.Equals("GET"))">
            <allow-access />
        </when>
    </choose>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <base />
</backend>
<outbound>
    <base />
</outbound>
<on-error>
    <base />
</on-error>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the moment I cannot imagine how to turn off subscription key checking conditionally per operation / method as it is clearly an API setting. But let's see if someone else has an idea.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to turn off the `Requires subscription` setting on the product and check the subscription key in the inbound policy by yourself. Here is an example of how to do it.

1. Go to **Settings** of Starter product.
2. Uncheck **Requires subscription** and save.
3. Open the policies of the product and add the following policy to the inbound. The value of `<check-header>` policy is the subscription key of the Starter product.

```xml
<choose>
    <when condition="@(!context.Request.Method.Equals("GET"))">
        <check-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" failed-check-httpcode="401" failed-check-error-message="Not authorized" ignore-case="false">
            <value>920b4e307f4f41ff9bd4a3bd6a5450ee</value>
        </check-header>
    </when>
</choose>
```

Comment: But... Are you hardcoding the subscription key? How do yo manage multiple subscriptions and multiple users? What if you have dozens of keys with their life cycle (add, expire, re-enable, etc)?