# How to expose some API methods without subscription while keeping subscription for others?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management to proxy requests from Internet to our backend systems. I have a Product entry on Azure Portal and an API entry associated with the product. Generally access to the API must be by subscription, but I would like the method returning OpenAPI specification (as well as probably few other methods) to be accessible without subscription (freely).

I see "Requires subscription" checkbox on the Product level as well as on API level, but not on a method's level. So I need either:

- bypass subscription check for certain methods while keeping access by subscription for others, or:
- same but vice versa: keep the access free for API, but enforce subscription check for certain methods (not preferable, as this fraction is greater).

I checked the [list of policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policies) and did not find anything applicable for my case. Moreover [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#scope-of-subscriptions) link states:

> Subscriptions can be associated with various scopes: product, all
> APIs, or an individual API.

Is there a way I can workaround this limitation?

Comment: Your request is similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900564/is-it-possible-to-create-a-policy-that-will-conditionally-expose-an-api-manageme/62926851#62926851. See my answer in it.

Answer (score 0):

I mean that, maybe you wanna some of the methods(less amount) in an Api can be called without a subscription while the left need. And I searched the ms document but failed to find such policy.

The link you provided also intended that. From my point of view,

> how about trying to add a separated Api containing those methods that
> don't need subscription?

Comment: That's an option, but it will require another URL suffix, as two APIs cannot share same URL suffix.